# seaborn remove legend in violin plot with swarmplots

Tags: python, plot, legend, swarmplot

I have made a violin plot with swarms like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AshZ4.png):

Is it possible to remove just the legend of the swarmplot? It seems the legend has 4 levels, but I just want the first 2 levels.

I tried `ax.legend_.remove()` but that remove all the legend.

This is the code I use to make the plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue = 'smoker', data=tips, color = 'white', dodge=True)
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",data=tips, palette="muted", ax = ax, )
```

But in the legend, it has four levels, I just hope to remove the legend level for the swarmplot (the black and white dots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was struggling with the same problem and couldn't find an answer, I decided to provide an answer myself. I am not sure if it's the optimal solution but here we go:

As you already figured out, the legend is stored in `ax.legend_`. The legend is simply a [`matplotlib.legend.Legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html?highlight=legend%20legend#matplotlib.legend.Legend) object and you can use its handles (`ax.legend_.legendHandles`) and labels (provided in `ax.legend_.texts` as a list of [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects) to update the legend. Calling [`plt.legend(handles, labels)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html?highlight=legend%20legend#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) with the handles from the violin plot and the corresponding labels recreates the legend without the swarm plot legend entries. (I switched the order of the two plot invocations to make the code simpler.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.violinplot(
    x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
    data=tips, palette="muted"
)
handles = ax.legend_.legendHandles
labels = [text.get_text() for text in ax.legend_.texts]

sns.swarmplot(
    x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
    data=tips, color="white", dodge=True,
    ax=ax    # you can remove this, it will be plotted on the current axis anyway
)

plt.legend(handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
#Your faulted example (what you are getting):
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips)
#The right way (what you want to get):
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",data=tips, palette="muted", ax = ax)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your case, the swarmplot does not show groups of smoker separately. I am trying to find some way to just remove the elements in the legend, without changing the plots.

Comment: Can you provide your code with some mock data to clarify what you mean?

Comment: @lftahP yes, I have adjusted your codes and updated my question to clarify what I want to plot. Many thanks!